# Windows Service slow performance after .Net Upgrade

Tags: .net, windows, performance, service

I am facing some performance issues in my application. Just to give you a brief overview of the app:
It's a windows service which basically picks up result set data from a SQL server(2012) creates a xml for each row that it has picked up and then processes this xml using web service(the code for which i don't have access to) in a db2 database. Now the real question this windows service was actually .Net Framework 2.0 app which i upgraded to .Net Framework 4.0 and after upgrading the performance of my windows service is reduced considerably(almost half). the variables such as Server configuration, Sql Server configuraions everything being the same difference being just in the framework my service processing speed has almost reduced to half. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason and what could be done to improve this performance.

let me know in case you need any information to better understand the question.

Thanks..

Comment: Post the code where most CPU time is spent.

Comment: when you upgraded, how exactly did you do it?  Did you just change the target framework?  I would check and see if there are newer versions of the referenced assemblies which you can point to if you haven't.

Comment: I upgraded my code by opening the code in VS2010 and it upgraded the code automatically, but yes I should check my referenced assemblies. Let me know if you have some other ideas as well which I can go through...there is one more thing when I deploy the same 4.0 code in my local machine it runs faster than usual but on the server it runs slow on the other hand if I deploy 2.0 on the server it runs at expected speed.

Comment: I just checked, we have pointed to 4.0 version of the assemblies everywhere...